# What if God in my world was like Immortal microbes/germs with hive mind?

Tags: gods, microorganisms, hive

I have been sitting on this one for a while. I decided to probe this a bit further and make it the world for my next work.

I think there are several parallels you could draw between this and our world.

I mean You were a micro organism before you were born right? (sperm?, egg? or both?) well you get the picture...

While you live you hose micro organisms, there are literally trillions in every inch of your body.

Also when you die you will decompose into microbes.

But what makes it harder for us to spot these microscopic parts of god is because there is no single type of god germ and because of hive-mind alerts from it's brethren (or part of itself) from within our body, it can either act dumb or evade detection.

It is extremely impossible to witness in actuality and it likes to enforce things like karma, luck etc.

I see a lot of possibilities. I wish to know if anyone would share my point of view and I really want to hear your thoughts on this. See things with a fresh pair of eyes really. Or if this would work at all?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Your question has several issues: first of all, there is a big misunderstanding of basic biology: sperm and eggs are not microorganism, and corpses do not turn into microorganisms either. That aside, our [help] clearly states that "what if " type of questions are not suited for this community. Give us a well defined problem and we will do our best to answer it. Give us a call for opinions or a fish for ideas and the question will be closed.

Comment: Sooo.... Midichlorians?